# Running multiple processes at once parallel in Google colab

Tags: parallel-processing, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I run a server on a Google colab notebook. On this server I want to run a main-process that waits for other sub-processes to do something.
When I run the main-process in a code cell, I see it's listening correctly to others with socket ports open and when I run a sub-process they put out an error because they miss the main-process.

I want to start first to run the main-process and in other cells the sub-process with the main-process still running.
But when I do so all other cells then the main-process cells are in a waiting line.

When I do this in (Ubuntu) Linux it works totally fine:
Start every process in a different terminal.

How can this be done with google colab (or jupyiter)?

I tried multiprocessing of Python which didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

It's still possible to run multiple processes at once using:

```
!nohup /usr/bin/python3 yourscript.py &
```

Just don't forget the symbol **&** at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It was possible with  putting `!nohub` in the beginning of each line of process to make it not blocking the terminal and finally `!tail -f nohup.out` to see the results.
I still don't know how to live check the process.